# How to write "Hello World" RESTful API using Python and then consume it

Tags: python, rest

I am totally new to Python. Can anybody guide me how to write and then consume a simple "Hello World" RESTful API in Python.

Comment: "RESTful API"?  Are you talking about creating a web server that responds to "REST" requests?  Or are you talking about creating a client proxy class that communicates with a RESTful web server?  What are you talking about?  Please be **specific**.  Also, please post any code you  have written so far.

Comment: @S Lott: I would like to have a web server that would reside a Hello World RESTful webservice written in Python (I want to write that Hello World webservice in Python that is residing at web server). Then I want to write a client proxy class written in Python to communicate with that RESTful web server.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using a WSGI “microframework” such as [Bottle](http://bottle.paws.de/docs/dev/index.html) or web.py.

Here's hello world with Bottle, taken directly from its home page:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/:name')
def index(name='World'):
    return '<b>Hello %s!</b>' % name

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: If someone could add instrucitons on how to install dependencies on top of vanilla python it would be helpful to people who are are looking for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would refer you to the excellent book [RESTful Web Services](http://books.google.com/books?id=XUaErakHsoAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=restful+web+services+richardson+and+ruby&source=bl&ots=5iimGotGrx&sig=0A4VgSFyKoKDn8-qJNCBqY6lyu8&hl=en&ei=wj0aTPyzCMXnnQfqn5SrCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CCYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false). It can get you started in REST with some Python examples. Also, you might want to consider writing some simpler Python code to increase your comfort level first. Welcome to Python - I hope it serves you as well as it has me!